# Makefile pair of target/dependency that share command but conflicts with implicit rules

Tags: makefile

I have many pairs of file-target/dependency with different extensions and I can't do an implicit rule because the pattern would be too general and would conflict with other implicit rules... Is there a way of sharing the rule's body in a short way ?

(for example, the target files are in an ordered variable, and the deps are in another variable ordered the same way)

for example :

```
foo.a : foo.b
    cmd1 $< $@

bar.a : bar.b
    cmd2 $< $@

foo1.a : foo.b
    cmd2 $< $@

bar1.a : foo.b
    cmd1 $< $@

foo2.a : something.b
    cmd2 $< $@

bar2.a : something2.b
    cmd1 $< $@
```

the names can be just random actually

Comment: please show some related code. it's too difficult to image.

Comment: You can loop over them or you can possibly use a static pattern rule (to prevent the "conflict with other implicit rules" bit.

Comment: to me, there are no things you can do better than this. if you want your makefile short, your need to make your dependencies predictable so that makefile can handle it automatically. otherwise, you need to spend your own work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it a little shorter:

```
foo.a bar1.a foo1.a : foo.b

bar2.a : something2.b

foo.a bar1.a bar2.a :
    cmd1 $< $@

bar.a : bar.b

foo2.a : something.b

bar.a foo1.a foo2.a :
    cmd2 $< $@
```

You could also construct all of those rules without commands from a pair of variables, as you suggested, but I don't advise it: the result would be a cryptic makefile, hard to understand or maintain.

Comment: So, in your last rule, $< is expended to the dep given above ?

Comment: @hl037_: Yes, try it.